# tkinterのButton()に設定した関数を、ボタンを押したときに動作するようにしたい

Tags: python, python3, tkinter

### 前提条件

**OS**
Windows 11 ProのWSL2上のUbuntu 22.04 LTS

**その他**
venv
VS Code上のJupyter

### 期待値

判定ボタンを押したときに、関数q_switch()を動作させる。

### 再現手順

下のPythonのコードを実行する。

```
from tkinter import *
import random

# お題のリスト
QUESTION = ["バナナ",
            "いちご",
            "パイナップル",
            "りんご",
            "イチジク",
            "きゅうり",
            "トマト",
            "なす"]     

root = Tk()
root.title("Typing Game")
root.geometry("500x500")

q_ran = random.choice(QUESTION)

def q_switch():
    var.set(q_ran)

# StringVarの設定
var = StringVar(root)
var.set(q_ran)

# Frameの設定
frame = Frame(root)

# Frameをpackで配置
frame.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)

# Widgetの設定
topic = Label(frame, text="お題: "+var) # お題をランダムに表示
button = Button(frame, text="判定！", command=q_switch()) # 押すと判定&お題が変更

# Widgetをpackで配置
topic.pack()
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

### その他

エラーメッセージ

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/kamome_run/practice-python/practice-venv/typing-game/typing-game.ipynb セル 2 line 2
     26 frame.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)
     28 # Widgetの設定
---> 29 topic = Label(frame, text="お題: "+var) # お題をランダムに表示
     30 button = Button(frame, text="判定！", command=q_switch()) # 押すと判定&お題が変更
     32 # Widgetをpackで配置

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "StringVar") to str
```

データ型がstrじゃないとvarと連結できないと出ていますが、変数varの中身はstr型のはずです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> # お題をランダムに表示
> # 押すと判定&お題が変更

```py
from tkinter import *
import random

# お題のリスト
QUESTION = ["バナナ",
            "いちご",
            "パイナップル",
            "りんご",
            "イチジク",
            "きゅうり",
            "トマト",
            "なす"]     

root = Tk()
root.title("Typing Game")
root.geometry("500x500")

# q_ran = random.choice(QUESTION)

def q_switch():
    global var
    var.set("お題: " + random.choice(QUESTION))

# StringVarの設定
var = StringVar(root)
var.set("お題: " + random.choice(QUESTION))

# Frameの設定
frame = Frame(root)

# Frameをpackで配置
frame.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)

# Widgetの設定
topic = Label(frame, textvariable=var) # お題をランダムに表示
button = Button(frame, text="判定！", command=q_switch) # 押すと判定&お題が変更

# Widgetをpackで配置
topic.pack()
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: 実行したところ、質問と同じエラーが出現しました。

Comment: コード全体を載せました。コピペして動作を確認してみてください。こちらの環境は Python 3.11.4/Tkinter 8.6.13 です。

Answer (score 1):

エラーの出ている

```
topic = Label(frame, text = "お題: " + var) # お題をランダムに表示
```

の部分は、

```
topic = Label(frame, text = "お題: " + var.get()) # お題をランダムに表示
```

とする必要があります。`StringVar` と `str` は型が違うというエラーが出ているわけです。`StringVar` そのものが `str` なのではなくて、`StringVar` から `get()` で値の `str` を取り出さなければなりません。